# Setting max-height on everything — best practice?

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a site that was coded by a third-party and I noticed they added the following declaration in their css file:

```
* {
    max-height: 99999px;
}
```

I'm wondering why the developer would have done this. I've tried to Google it and have not found any resources. Can you think of any reasons/advantages to doing this?

Comment: Looks a bit odd. Maybe the developer wanted to limit the page height? But a very long one.

Comment: They probably had an issue with it and just wanted to expilictly tell each element to have that as a base max height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was reading articles this weekend and I came to know that using `max-height` set to `99999px` does make sense in some cases...

It is especially used to prevent Font Boosting in mobile browsers... So using something like

```
* {
    max-height: 99999px;
}
```

Along with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

does prevent font boosting, just implemented on one of my projects and it worked.

[For more information on Font Boosting](http://www.patrickcatanzariti.com/2013/03/font-boosting/)

---

Previous Answer —

To be true it's useless, first of all it's very very very rare chances <sup>*(Actually not possible for a standard website/document)*</sup> to get the page to that `height`, secondly it applies to all the elements which again is useless, none of your `button`, `input`, `a` etc will be that big.

So basic answer is **NO**, don't use it, there are no side effects as such, unless your element reaches that `height` *(which it won't)*, so the disadvantage is performance, the developer is assigning that property to ALL the elements using `*` selector which is a universal selector... So applying a property to all the elements in the DOM which is not useful is bad, thus it impacts performance.

---

If for SOME reason you want to use it, be specific and use, say, you doubt that certain element can flow but shouldn't flow say out of `1000px` in `height` so instead of assigning that to all the elements, make a specific selector and use it like say

```
div.class_name {
   max-height: 1000px;
}
```

That way, it's specific, and also, optimized, and lastly, meaningful.

Comment: Well thought out response. Thanks!